# Droid X not connecting to adb on OS X

Tags: android

I got a Droid X for development, and after setting it up just like all my other test devices, it showed nothing when I ran "adb devices".  When I plugged it in each time, OS X complained that it could not connect to the mass storage device.

How can I fix this, and connect my Droid X to OS X for development?

Finally found the answer, so I wanted to share it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Droid X ships with USB mode set to "PC Mode" by default.  It needs to be set to "USB Mass Storage" mode.

To do this, touch the USB icon in the status bar and drag it down.  Touch "USB Connection" and select "USB Mass Storage" mode.

Thanks for this answer go to EricC (apparently a Motorola employee), found [here](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Studio-for-Android/Droid-X-not-appearing-in-device-list-in-MOTODEV-for-OSX/m-p/6389).

Comment: Hi Doug. Yes, that's me and I'm a Motorola employee.  I occasionally drop by StackOverflow to check on questions about MOTODEV Studio.  Enjoy your DroidX!

Comment: Yes, I would just like to add that the previous was also applicable to me on OS X, but with a different device.  I could not see the device on `adb devices` until I toggled out of "USB Mass Storage" mode on the unit itself.  The device in question was an unreleased tablet with (apparently) an HTC USB chipset.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, USB Mass Storage mode usually presents the phone to the host as a file drive. To setup ADB you usually need to go to Settings > Applications > Development and select USB Debugging.

Comment: That's part of the process for any android phone.  The Droid X is unique in that it ships with USB connectivity set to PC Mode.